# How can I have R identify text in one column and then use it to create data in another column?

Tags: r

I have materials lists from vendors that I would like to expand the description to other columns so I can use the filter function Excel to more easily find products based on their description. He's an example of the description I receive from a vendor:

```
2 SS 150LB 304L SLIP ON FLANGE
```

I would like to take this description and have R identify certain bits of text, and based on that text, add data to another column. For instance: if the string "SS" is in this cell, then put the word "STAINLESS" in a Materials column. If the string "BLK" is found in this cell, then put the word "BLACK" in the Materials column. If the string "FLANGE" is found in this cell, then put the word "FLANGE" in another column called Part_Type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple approach which looks for certain character sequences to use as a trigger to add strings to other columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(('2 SS 150LB 304L SLIP ON FLANGE'),
       ('3 BLK ON FLANGE')))


# add new columns filled with NA
df <- df %>% 
  add_column(Materials = NA_character_) %>% 
  add_column(Part_Type = NA_character_)

df %>% 
  mutate(Materials = if_else(str_detect(x, 'SS'), 'STAINLESS', Materials)) %>% 
  mutate(Materials = if_else(str_detect(x, 'BLK'), 'BLACK', Materials)) %>% 
  mutate(Part_type = if_else(str_detect(x, 'FLANGE'),'FLANGE', Part_Type))
```

Can an item be both 'stainless steel' and 'black'?  i.e. do we want to add multiple strings to one column?  In that case, it would be necessary to append rather than overwrite.  Here's one approach to that problem.

```
my_nrow = 2

df <- tibble(x = c(('2 SS 150LB 304L SLIP ON FLANGE'),
                 ('3 BLK SS ON FLANGE')),
       Materials = vector('character', my_nrow), 
       Part_type = vector('character', my_nrow))

df

df %>% 
  mutate(Materials = ifelse(str_detect(x, 'SS'), str_c(Materials,'STAINLESS '), Materials)) %>% 
  mutate(Materials = if_else(str_detect(x, 'BLK'), str_c(Materials,'BLACK '), Materials)) %>% 
  mutate(Part_type = if_else(str_detect(x, 'FLANGE'), str_c(Part_type,'FLANGE', sep = ' '), Part_type))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, Dr. Ladson!  One clarification:  Can I replace the x = c(('2 SS 150LB 304L SLIP ON FLANGE'),
       ('3 BLK ON FLANGE')) with a reference to the "Description" column?  e.g., df <- tibble(x = Description)

Comment: @Matt B. That should work provided you set my_nrow to length(Description)